# Best approach for several steps with user input in between

Tags: design-patterns, .net, winforms

I've read several questions and I couldn't find one specifically similar to mine. I also don't think there's a design pattern for this situation as I think my system is a legacy system and don't fit the "best practices" in many parts of it.

I'm rewriting a legacy feature from a 1990's system to a "new" system in .net, but I have to keep using the same database and data structures. So, I cannot reinvent the wheel regarding separating data access, OOP, etc. It's a WinForms app that will be able to query/change the database. And we have very few programmers, so I want to keep the code simple, to make maintenance easy in a distant future.

Now the question:

The feature I'm working on, after the user hits "Save" button, it has several steps and conditions, including some parts where we need to get the user's Yes/No input and continue based on that. For instance (fictional pseudo-code):

```cs
public void save_click() {
  var transaction = ...; // code to start a transaction

  if (cmbStatus = "Close")
  {
    // validations.
    ...
    var completed = DataAccessLayer.GetStatusForOrder(txtOrder);
    if (completed) {
      var userInput = MessageBox.Show("Order is completed, continue anyway?", YesNoButtons);
      if (userInput = No) {
        transaction.Rollback;
        return;
      }
      // means user hit Yes
      DataAccessLayer.InsertToAlarmsTable(...);
      // validate delivery:
      var deliveryDate = DataAccessLayer.GetDeliveryDate(txtOrder);
      if (deliveryDate < DateTime.Now) {
        MessageBox.Show("wrong date. Cannot close");
        transaction.Rollback;
        return;
      }
    } else {
      // not completed
      DataAccessLayer.ADifferentUpdateToAnotherTable(...);
    }
  } else if (other status) {
    // in here other conditions and other table updates
    if (txtTax = 100) {
      // a msgBox that warns the user but continues anyway:
      MessageBox.Show("Warning: tax is 100, check with Sales after the update.");
      DataAccessLayer.InsertAlarmsTable(...);
    }
  }

  if (txtPrice > 1000) {
    MessageBox.Show("Too expensive.");
    transaction.Rollback;
    return;
  }

  // at the end, do the main Update
  DataAccessLayer.UpdateOrderTable(...);
  DataAccessLayer.UpdateTaxTable(...);
  
  if (some other stuff) {
    // some other updates
  }

  // if all above was successful, commit:
  transaction.Commit();
}
```

My problem with it is that it's becoming too monolithic and these MessageBox and transaction.Rollback and early *returns* are making me nervous. It does not *feel* right. You know?

I'm in search of a way to chain these validations and conditions in a way that I can choose what to do next based on previous validation result. And still be able to warn the user when needed and get user input when needed.

**My first idea: separate methods returning (bool, string)**

My first solution to this was to have separate methods returning a tuple of (bool success, string messages), but I didn't like all the **ifs** to continue:

```cs
if (status = "Close") {
  var v = ValidateStatusCompleted(...);
  if (!v.success) {
    transaction.Rollback();
    MessageBox.Show(v.messages);
    return;
  }

  v = ValidateDeliveryDate();
  if (!v.success) {
    transaction.Rollback();
    MessageBox.Show(v.messages);
    return;
  }

  ... and so on
}
```

That improved a bit, but was still too verbose on non-business logic stuff. So it led me to:

**Second idea: Exceptions**

I think using exceptions make it look much better:

```cs
var transaction = ...;
try {
  if (status = "Close") {
    ValidateStatusCompleted(); // This has a Yes/No msgBox inside it
    ValidateDeliveryDate();
  } else if (otherStatus) {
    ValidateSomethingElse();
  } else if (other) {}

  DoSaveToDB();
  transaction.Commit();
    
} catch(ApplicationException exc) {
  MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
  transaction.Rollback();
}
```

But then if you invest too much time reading stuff online, you'll end up finding people saying that Exceptions should not be used for business logic control.

So I wanted to know if there's some other design pattern that I don't know and I could be using here to solve my problem while keeping the code simple.

I don't want this question to be too subjective, I've tried my best to make it look like a real-world scenario that other people might be having as well. I just want to know if there's some easier way to solve it that I've never heard of before.

Comment: The formatting of this old blog post has not survived Microsoft's many redesigns over the years, but Microsoft's typical recommendation for WinForms to approach this is to use Model-View-Presenter (MVP) as a means of separating your application logic away from anything which happens to use GUI controls (MessageBox is a GUI control from the point of view of the MVP pattern) -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/august/design-patterns-model-view-presenter

Comment: This blog takes that one step further and pulls in a hand-written EventAggregator  https://markheath.net/post/model-view-presenter-winforms    (I assume the example probably predates Jimmy Bogard's `MediatR` library -- EventAggregator is the name used by the old Microsoft Patterns&Practices team who designed the MVVM Prism Framework, but the principle is the same)

Comment: Awesome, thank you Ben, I'll take a look at both! Thanks